# How to mining GETH

Tags: go-ethereum

I  wanna try run my 1st node on GETH , where  can start mining this geth ? Any1 can help  step by step please becouse  this is new world for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum is now a proof of stake blockchain. You cannot mine as it used to be several years ago.

If you wan to run your own node with staking you can start from here https://ethereum.org/staking.